# How to draw a grid over and image that won't be printed?

Tags: drawing, tool-selection

In high school, I used to print images, draw grids over them and carry them around in my sketch book. Now, I have my smartphone with me all the time and am almost never near a cheap and easy printer. Needless to say, I usually use my phone to find art projects or inspiration images.

Is there a software or website that can quickly draw a grid (of my chosen size) over an image on my smartphone that can be saved to my device? It would make my art projects and sketching from a photo a lot easier.

Comment: Make a stencil or template or such on a cardboard or thick paper. Guess all your printouts are A4, so you can make a template to that proportion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Jackson's ArtGrid](https://www.jacksonsart.com/artgrid) which is available for IOS and Android. You have the ability to control the grid dimensions, style of grid, etc. It also has a greyscale function which is really nice for working out the tonal ranges in an image. Finally, you can save, share, and print the result which can be edited and tweaked later.

Not bad, I like it. The interface could be a bit better, but it does the job and does it well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! thank you John

Answer (score 2):

A low tech solution is to print a grid onto acetate, cut it out and just lay it over the image you want to copy. This has the advantage that it will work on any medium and is quick and easy to use once you have made your grid. You could also have different grid spacing for different applications.

You could also glue it into a card mount to make sure it lays flat.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few grid drawings apps for the iPhone that I know of. Look up "drawing grid" and "artist grid drawing tool". Some are free with ads, some of them cost a couple of dollars.